# Metamask doesn't show token value on erc20 contract interaction

Tags: web3js, tokens, metamask, transfer

Why using the Transfer method is showing the value of the erc20 that I want to transfer while with a custom method is always showing 0 ETH on metamask instead of the token that I'm transferring via the contract? Is there a way to show the value of the erc20 that the users are transferring using my custom function and isn't it dangerous to let user transfers all their erc20 tokens while they only see 0 ETH on metamask...

Please note that with transfer method I mean transaction data is `contract.methods.transfer(...`
and with custom method I mean data is `contract.methods.mycustomcontractfunction(...`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that MetaMask only shows an ERC20 transfer if the function signature is transfer or transferFrom.

The problem is that until the transaction is mined in a block it not possible to be sure the transaction involves an ERC20 token transfer.